# Knowing which django subquery matched a row

Tags: django

In a django 1.6 application, I have a line of code looking like this:

```
data = query_set.filter(Q1 | Q2).values('pk', *fields)
```

Now I find that the later code processing data need to know which of the rows matched Q1 and which did not. I tried the this:

```
data = (query_set.filter(Q1).extra(select={'matched_q1': 1}) |
        query_set.filter(Q2)).values('pk', *fields)
```

This however did not work as expected, since the `matched_q1` value got applied to all rows, even those which only matched Q2 but did not match Q1.

Is there some way I can update the query to know from the result which of the rows matched the first Q object?

Comment: About how many rows we are talking about? 10, 1k, 1M? Is performance important?

Comment: @danihp The code is used on many different tables. The largest has 3M rows and it is growing. The number of matching rows varies between 0 and 10K. Performance is important. I do not yet know my exact performance requirements for this query, since it depends on how much I can speed rest of the function up (currently it is 10x slower than acceptable.)

Comment: @danihp I can probably afford this approach: Use the original query as is. Next if any results were produced evaluate `query_set.filter(Q1).values('pk')`. In my case I expect 50% of the time the number of matched rows will be 0.

Comment: @user21904 In the end I used two separate queries.